# NoClassDefFoundError: Could Not Initialise class org.apache.spark.package

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-mllib

I am attempting to make some changes to the apache spark's MLLib. I cloned latest spark repo from [Github](https://github.com/apache/spark), opened up MLLib as a project in IntelliJ with `JDK 1.8.0` and `scala-sdk-2.12.6`, and created a scratch file to make sure I could run things.

Here's all the code presently being tested:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("IncrementalCB").getOrCreate()
```

It returns the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.package$
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$1(scratch_1.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo(scratch_1.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo$(scratch_1.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.logInfo(scratch_1.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(scratch_1.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(scratch_1.scala:2508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(scratch_1.scala:942)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(scratch_1.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(scratch_1.scala:933)
    at #worksheet#.spark$lzycompute(scratch_1.scala:2)
    at #worksheet#.spark(scratch_1.scala:2)
    at #worksheet#.get$$instance$$spark(scratch_1.scala:2)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(scratch_1.scala:10)
```

While I'm not quite sure what the situation, I suspect it may be something JAR or version related. Anyone care to fill in the blanks? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First: YOu don't need to clone Spark repository from GitHub to work with spark.

Second: Instead of using scratch file - it's better to set-up a project with either [maven](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/02/setting-up-a-spark-project-with-maven.html) or [sbt](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/creating-a-spark-project-with-sbt-intellij-sbt-spark-package-and-friends-cc9108751c28).

They will save you a time buy downloading all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Vladislav. I am aware a clone isn't necessary to work with Spark. In my case, I am trying to make changes to Spark's source code, and the scratch file is used to simply test functions as I change them. Would you have any insight into resolving the error message above?

Comment: Have you compiled cloned Spark project?

Comment: In general - there is unit tests in the spark project. I would just create unit tests to reproduce certain error that you are having. You can take as example already existing tests. Anyway it's good practice to do unit tests.